# Tmux and copy mode with release mouse button

Tags: tmux

I'm using tmux for the first time as a replacement for iterm (mostly because of the split panels function) and it works great. Now, i have a question about the copy-text behaviour.

It's possible to configure tmux, so i can select text with the left button (in copy mode) and it's automatically copied (to the clipboard) when i release the left button? (same as in irc clients)

Answer (score 0):

Tmux’s *select* behavior will depend on your mouse settings. If `mode-mouse` is off, Tmux should stay out of the way. But, by default, it may be set to “on”. Then it will use its own “paste buffer”. To bypass that, you can **hold down `shift` while selecting and pasting**. (This works on Linuxes, but probably on Mac, too; not sure what OS you’re on.)

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my question.. I know that about the shift, and that i can also bind other keys to the same action, my point is, that if somehow can i bypass pressing a key for copying and got the 'copy action' binded to releasing the mouse button. So, in plain words, that when i select text (in more-mouse on, obviously) it got automatically copied to the cb.